# Executing R script ssh and nohup

Tags: r, ssh, nohup

I have the `R` file `test.R` in a remote server. It contains only this:

```
Sys.sleep(5)
```

In my local machine I have my `local.R` file:

```
library(ssh)

host<-"root@someip"
keyfile<-"mykeyfile.osh"
passwd<-"mypassword"

ssh_session <- ssh::ssh_connect(host,keyfile,passwd)

print(Sys.time())
a<-ssh::ssh_exec_wait(ssh_session,
                      command = 'nohup R CMD BATCH test.R &')
print(Sys.time())

ssh::ssh_disconnect(ssh_session)
```

When I execute `local.R`, I have this output:

```
[1] "2023-09-16 17:41:52.707577 CEST"
[1] "2023-09-16 17:41:58.132833 CEST"
```

If you observe, the difference between both times is more than 5 seconds. What I expect is the second print not to wait till to finalize the execution of `test.R`. My final goal is to make it work from a `shiny` app.

EDIT. I also used `command = 'nohup Rscript test.R &'`, but the result quite the same.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `R CMD BATCH` is obsolete (and has been, for over a decade, I think). Use `Rscript` instead.

Comment: I used `command = 'nohup Rscript test.R &'`, but the result quite the same. Ill edit the question.

Comment: As for the question, this seems to be unrelated to R but rather a property of the actual SSH command (which is what the `ssh` uses under the hood, via its C library). But I’m afraid I have no idea how to avoid that.  — With the command line `ssh` utility you’d have to specify `-t` to avoid waiting for the pipes’ EOF, but `ssh::ssh_exec_wait()` doesn’t seem to allow this. In fact, [if I’m reading the source code correctly](https://github.com/ropensci/ssh/blob/e9871f8dc1983849b32d658ba4a9f65e1f24fc86/src/command.c#L36C42-L36C60) then waiting for pipe EOF is hard-coded inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `ssh_exec_wait()` *always* waits for the server-side standard output and error streams to be closed. Incidentally, this is the same behaviour as that of the `ssh` command line utility unless pseudo-terminal allocation via the `-t` option is forced.

One option to avoid the wait is therefore to redirect the command’s output and error streams to detach them from the terminal:

```
a <- ssh::ssh_exec_wait(
  ssh_session,
  command = 'nohup Rscript test.R >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
)
```

Beware that the above will (obviously) discard any output. If you *need* the output you either need to adjust your script, or alternatively perform redirection into a suitable file.